# Call a java method to generate SQL query in myBatis

Tags: java, sql, mybatis, ibatis

I am using myBatis to write some SQL queries, the problem is that I have tables that have several columns  ( around 50 column). So writing the `insert` query like this :

```
<insert id="insert" parameterType="com.atos.tables.Table1>
  insert into ot ( id, c1, c2, ....,c50) values (#{id}, #{c1},#{c2},... #{c50})
</insert>
```

is very tedious.

I can create a method in java that generate the `String` of the queries automatically, but how can I call this method from the `mapper.xml` ?

And if I use myBatis annotations I cannot call a method in an interface.
I don't know if I am missing something, is there a way to do this??

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way I'm aware of for doing this directly.

What you could try is to generate the columns at compile or deploy time in a separate file as [`<sql>` elements and then include them](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#sql) in your mapper files as needed.

There is also this [statement-builders](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/statement-builders.html) feature added to MyBatis that alows you to build SQL from code so maybe have a look at that also.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is not in query string generation: this can be done easily using scripting support for example with  [mybatis-velocity](http://mybatis.github.io/velocity-scripting/).

The main problem is to set parameters dynamically. This can done in mybatis-velocity by defining custom directive which will dynamically create `org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ParameterMapping`.

It may be used in mapper like this:

```
<insert id="insert">
   insert into ot (
     #field_names('com.atos.tables.Table1')
   ) values ( @{id},
     #params_for_fields('com.atos.tables.Table1')
   )
</insert>
```

Here `#field_names` adn #params_for_fields is a custom directives which you need to implement. 
`field_names` should iterate over fields of class which is passed as argument and generate comma separated list of field.

`params_for_fields` should create new parameters mapping and add them to list of parameters mappings maintained by velocity language driver.

You may look to built-in [repeat](https://github.com/mybatis/velocity-scripting/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mybatis/scripting/velocity/RepeatDirective.java) directive and [ParameterMappingCollector](https://github.com/mybatis/velocity-scripting/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mybatis/scripting/velocity/ParameterMappingCollector.java) to see how parameter mappings can be created and accessed.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that my fields have complex name (is not c1 , c2.. I used these names only to simplify), In the method of generation of the query I get the fields from the class and I generate the query.

Comment: This is not a problem. You can shape custom directives so you can create directives which iterates over the fields of a class. I've updated the answer.